# Eager loading conditional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the following class:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :adverts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many  :active_adverts, :class_name => 'Advert', :select => "adverts.id, adverts.availability_state, adverts.source_name, adverts.last_observed_at", :conditions => "availability_state = 'active'"

end
```

When I do: `cars = Car.where(:brand => 'BMW').includes(:adverts)` it works fine, and returns me an array of the cars that I requested, and the adverts are eager loaded correctly.

How ever if I do: `cars = Car.where(:brand => 'BMW').includes(:active_adverts)` it seems to execute the expected queries, but it returns me an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and if I ask `cars.first` I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@au/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:88:in `block in associated_records_by_owner'
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I followed the advice her: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Where it states:

> If you do want eager load only some members of an association it is
>   usually more natural to include an association which has conditions
>   defined on it:
>
> ```
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :approved_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :conditions => ['approved = ?', true]
> end
> ```
>
> Post.includes(:approved_comments) This will load posts and eager load
>   the approved_comments association, which contains only those comments
>   that have been approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, forgot to select the foreign key `car_id` in the select.